# Create a Web Navigation Menu from XML Sitemap

Tags: createelement

I noticed this while I was catching up on the XML protocol: "...extend the Sitemaps protocol using your own namespace." [Click here to view the reference (sitemap.org).](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#extending)

What extra functionality does this provide, and why is having your own namespace important?

This is a new area for me, and I'd like to build my skillset... with this community's help!

What I'm wanting to do is create a vertical accordion menu for a large site I manage. The tool I use can create a menu, but it also doesn't allow me full control in all situations. So, I'm looking for ways to reliably and successfully create my own menu using the data I already have.

:)

Jim